# How to extract an alphanumeric string from a sentence if a starting point and end point is given

Tags: python, regex

I have a string something like this:
"GAP-88 (R 07/17) (STOCK REORDER NUMBER)"

I want to extract starting from "G" up till "7"

I have to use python for doing this.
Also the desired result should look something like this:

"GAP88R0717"

The ending character can be 7 or 9 or 4.

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have tried the split function as well the partition... Couple of regex also.. But they do not seem to give me the proper result. Kind of newbie in python so facing an issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex

**Code**

```
import re

def extract(text):
    '''
       extract substring
    '''
    pattern = r'^G.*[794]'  # pattern ends in 7, 9, 4
    
    # Find pattern in text
    m = re.match(pattern, text)       # find pattern in string
    if m:
        # Found pattern substring
        # Remove space, \, (, - by replacing with empty string
        m = re.sub(r'[ \(/-]', '', m.group())
    return m
```

**Usage**

```
s = "GAP-88 (R 07/17) (STOCK REORDER NUMBER)"
print(extract(s))   # Output: GAP88R0717
```

**Explanation**

```
r'^G.*[794]'          - regex match pattern
'^G                   - match strings that begins with G
.*[794]               - greedily match all characters 
                        until last 7, 9, or 4 
                        in string
```

**Follow up Question**

To detect text word after (STOCK REORDER NUMBER)

*Code*

```
def postfix(text):
    '''
        Extract text after (STOCK REORDER NUMBER)
    '''
    pattern = r'\(STOCK REORDER NUMBER\)\s(\w+)'
    m = re.search(pattern, text)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return ''
```

*Usage*

```
s = "GAP-88 (R 07/17) (STOCK REORDER NUMBER) abc123"
print(postfix(s)) # Output: abc123

print(extract(s) + ' ' + postfix(s))
# Output: GAP88R0717 abc123
```

Comment: What is the regex in re.match I should use?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra--sorry, typo in the solution statement.  Is it clear now how re.match works?

Comment: @darryIG - while I am onto it... For example if after (STOCK REORDER NUMBER) there is some text like abc123 then what should be the modifications in code?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra--added some follow up code for detecting text after (STOCK REORDER NUMBER).  This assumed you just wanted the immediate word.  Let me know if you want all the words i.e. if text is (STOCK REORDER NUMBER) abc123 hello world, you want abc123 hello world

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the perfect library. Here's the code:

```
import re
def get_alnum(string, start_index, end_index):
    alnums = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9]', string[start_index:end_index+1])
    return "".join(alnums)
```

Usage:

```
st = 'GAP-88 (R 07/17) (STOCK REORDER NUMBER)'
print(get_alnums(st, 0, 14)) #0 is index of 'G' and 14 is index of '7' in string
```